# Symfony/flex problem installing stof_doctrine_extensions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-extensions

I'm trying to use slugs for my symfony project. The first thing that I wanted to do is to install StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle. I tried to follow the tutorial in symfony website

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html

The result of the command : composer require stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle is

```
Using version ^1.6 for stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating optimized autoload files
composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
52 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]

Nothing to unpack
```

It seemed ok for me but a file called "stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml" should ve been generated and was not created automatically. For now I tried to create manually the file I honestly don't know if it's a good move here's what my file looks like

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
  default_locale: en_US
  orm:
      default:
          sluggable: true
```

I still didn't figure it out the error now is :

```
/stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml"). Looked for namespace "stof_doctrine_extensions", found ""framework", "maker", "twig", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "web_server"" in /config/packages/stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml (which is being imported from "/src/Kernel.php").
```

If anyone could help I would be really grateful

Comment: The namespance is missing. Did you register the bundle https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/installation.html#step-2-enable-the-bundle?

Comment: @Vyctorya you shouldn't need to register bundles if you're using flex, which OP has mentioned. Make sure that your namespace is defined in your `composer.json`. E.g.: `"autoload": { "psr-4": { "App\\": "src/" } }`